# Angular 7 - Add custom babel plugin to build chain

Tags: angular, angular-cli, babeljs, angular7, angular-schematics

I want to add the `optional-chaining` babel plugin to my Angular 7 build but can't find any documentation on if it's possible to add a `.babelrc` or schematic to my current project to amend/add custom plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible.

You can find the angular-cli repo conversation [over here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10618) which describes the community attitude and possible solutions.

*UPD:* There is a tool [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) which could partially fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Angular officially doesn't support Babel, so you would need to wire up it yourself with ngx-build-plus or completely exiting the cli.